# RegEx Start With Letter or Number 0

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx that starts with the number 0 or ANY Letter (basically it can't start with 1-9). It also must be 13 characters long

I have this but it does not seem to work:

```
"^[0][a-zA-Z]{13}"
```

Comment: Your RegEx translates to "'0' followed by 13 letters".

Comment: @gbulmer It is not homework.  Working on making a search that will perform specific types of searches based on users input.

Comment: okay - I used to teach this, and it looked like a tutorial exercise.

Comment: Is this your homework, Larry?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
"^[0a-zA-Z].{12}$"
```

`[0a-zA-Z]` means "one character, that is either a 0, one of a-z, or one of A-Z".

`.{12}` means twelve more characters, whatever they are.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  This worked great.  I had something similar earlier but did not use the .{12} and was using {13} instead.

Comment: If I wanted the last twelve to be numbers would I do `"^[0a-zA-Z][0-9].{12}$"` ?

Comment: @mint `"^[0a-zA-Z][0-9]{12}$"`

Comment: @gbulmer I tried that and it didn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: @mint - what do you mean it did not work? The only difference between your suggestion and mine, is yours matched [0a-zA-Z][0-9] then 12 of any character, followed by end of line; where as mine matches twelve digits (which is what you asked about), followed by end of line.

Comment: @gbulmer I apologize, it does work.  I had code in front of that that heeded it from being called.  Thanks for your help gbulmer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this:

```
^[0\w]\S{12}$
```

This states the first character must be 0 or a word character.  Followed by exactly 12 characters that are NOT whitespace (this allows 0-9, characters and special characters.  Repace the \S with anything you like.  Such as [0-9\w]

A great playground to test regular expressions is at: http://regexpal.com/  I use it constantly to test regular expressions.